Feedback on Flutter BottomNavigationBar Implementation
This is my current bottom navbar:

I want to achieve bottom navbar like an i phone dock:

I'm working on a Flutter app and just implemented a BottomNavigationBar with a custom AppBar. Below is the code for my HomePage widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui'; // For ImageFilter.blur

import 'screens/profile.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'book_appointment.dart';
import 'screens/history.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _bottomNavIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    AppointmentPage(),
    HistoryPage(),
  ];

  final List<IconData> _iconList = [
    Icons.home_filled,
    Icons.add_rounded,
    Icons.history,
  ];

  final List<String> _titleList = [
    'Home',
    'Appointments',
    'History',
  ];

  PreferredSizeWidget? _buildAppBar() {
    if (_bottomNavIndex == 0) {
      return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/appbar.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage()),
              );
            },
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/pogisivenz.png'),
                    radius: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text(
                  'Hi, Harold Pogi',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE5D9F2)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white, // Background color for the dock
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(30), // Rounded corners at the top
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
        ],
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0), // Margin for the floating effect
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(30), // Match the top rounded corners
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(_iconList[0]),
              label: _titleList[0],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(_iconList[1]),
              label: _titleList[1],
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(_iconList[2]),
              label: _titleList[2],
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
          selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 116, 23, 133),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _bottomNavIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // Make Scaffold background transparent
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/splash.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              child: _pages[_bottomNavIndex],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}

I tried changing it on my own many times but its not working pls help

There's a few mistake in your code:

You use BorderRadius.vertical instead of BorderRadius.all or BorderRadius.circular, the vertical one only rounded your top side corner, otherwise all and circular will rounded all the corner.
If you use Container for rounding the corner, you don't need to use ClipRRect again, because Container already has a property named clipBehavior.

Change your _buildBottomNavigationBar() to this one and hope it'll fulfill your needs.
Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
        ],
      ),
      // Add [Clip.hardEdge] to [Container] so the child will forced
      // to implement the [Container] decoration.
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      // Add all side margin just like iphone dock.
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        // [backgroundColor] is the properties to set
        // [BottomNavigationBar] background.
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(TestPage._iconList[0]),
            label: TestPage._titleList[0],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(TestPage._iconList[1]),
            label: TestPage._titleList[1],
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(TestPage._iconList[2]),
            label: TestPage._titleList[2],
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
        selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 116, 23, 133),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: (index) {
          _bottomNavIndex = index;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }

The Output

